# How to make a response to contentScript from nested callbacks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to send result of the executed script to the contentScript as an response but obviously i'm doing something wrong. Chrome keep throwing an error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
(request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "example.com"}, tab => {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: var x = 10; x}, function (result) {
            sendResponse(result);    
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You have to return `true` from your `onMessage` listener in order to use `sendResponse` asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return `true` from your listener, like:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
(request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "example.com"}, tab => {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'var x = 10; x'}, function (result) {
            sendResponse(result);    
        });
    });
    return true;
});
```